# Full width jumbotron image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make the image have the same width as the browser screen. It needs to be responsive. I'm new at bootstrap 3 so any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is a code playground like for you to see exactly what I mean.

http://bootply.com/98241

You will see the jumbotron image is left aligned. I need it to stretch the full width of the page.

Comment: The full width of the entire page no matter the width, or just the full width of the container which holds the rest of the content on your page?

Comment: Full width of the entire page no matter the width of the container

Comment: I think you also need to look at the `<div class="container">` because using the container class adds a margin left/right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the img width 100%..

```
.widewrapper {
  width:100%;
  }

.widewrapper > img {
  width:100%;
}
```

## [Bootply](http://bootply.com/98247)

Comment: Its usually good to create a custom.css and add new rules to it and then reference that from the html. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623441/twitter-bootstrap-custom-css-inclusion

Comment: Sure, but that has little to do with getting the full width image which the CSS above accomplishes.

Answer (score 12):

According to the Bootstrap documentation, to make `.jumbotron` full width, take it outside of any `.container`.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. I took mine outside of the container in html and used the following code in my CSS:

```
jumbotron {
position: relative;
background: url("img.url") no-repeat center center;
width:100%;
height: 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```