# Bootstrap 3 apply class on only col-md and col-lg class but not on col-sd class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 divs with same structure,
so for large and medium it is 3+3+3= 9, So I have 3 columns left, Is it a good idea to create a class myself with margin calculation myself( I have to margin 1.5 column from both sides to make it look in center)

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-lg-push-1.5">
  <article>
    <header>
    </header>
  </article>
</div>
```

Custom margins are solving problem on big screens but on small screen not looking good.

Note: I have found the solution I modified the bootstrap css, and placed a class

```
.col-md-lg-push-1.5 {
  left: 12.5%;
}
```

and pasted this in several positions like,

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 990px) { 
   .col-md-lg-push-1.5 {
     left: 2.5%;
   }
}

@media (min-width: 990px) {
   .col-md-lg-push-1.5 {
     left: 12.5%;
   }
}
```

Comment: Its best to create a custom.css and add all your new styles there it'll get overwritten if need be and reference that in your head section. try these two: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623441/twitter-bootstrap-custom-css-inclusion http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/12/customizing-bootstrap/

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623441/twitter-bootstrap-custom-css-inclusion
  [2]: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/12/customizing-bootstrap/

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for but quite close, thanks.

Comment: No probs, I not quite sure what you are asking for.